# Conversion from u-law to PCM, 16 bit

Tags: c, pcm, mu-law

I am currently using two functions in my C source code to convert A-law files to PCM 16 bit and U-law files to PCM 16 bit. The conversion of U-law files to PCM 16 bit is not successfull. There is a lot of noise to the produced PCM 16 bit file.

Below there are the two functions:

```
short ALawToPcm16(char c)
{
    int i;
    short val;

    i = (c & 0x00FF) ^ 0x0055;

    if (i > 0x007F)
    {
        val = (short)(0x10000 - AIndexToPcm16Bit[i - 0x80]);
    }
    else
    {
        val = AIndexToPcm16Bit[i];
    }

    return(val);
}


short FctMuLawToPcm16(char c)
{
    int i;
    short val;

    i = (c & 0x00FF);

    if (i > 0x007F)
    {
        val = (short)(0x10000 - UIndexToPcm16Bit[i - 0x80]);
    }
    else
    {
        val = UIndexToPcm16Bit[i];
    }

    return(val);
}
```

Can anyone please tell me what is wrong with the second function?
Thanks

Comment: Try replacing `i = (c & 0x00FF);` with `i = (c & 0x00FF) ^ 0x00FF;`

Comment: Also, you might need to replace `val = (short)(0x10000 - UIndexToPcm16Bit[i - 0x80]);` with `val = (short)(0x10000 - UIndexToPcm16Bit[i - 0x80] - 1);`

Comment: It worked by adding just the first comment in my source code. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry, who are `UIndexToPcm16Bit` and `AIndexToPcm16Bit`?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `i = (c & 0x00FF);` with `i = (c & 0x00FF) ^ 0x00FF;`
                    – Ian Abbott